# How can I use hook_views_query_alter()?

Tags: views, 8

How can I implement `hook_views_query_alter()` in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7, I could use the following code.

```
$args = arg;
$node = menu_get_object();

if ($args[0] === 'my_view') {
  $query->orderBy('node_field_data_created','ASC');
  if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'category') {
        $filters = $query->getFilters();
        $first_filter = $filters[0];
        if ($first_filter['#value'] == "(category) AND node_field_data.status:(1)") {
            $query->condition('field_category', $node->nid, '=');
        }
```

In Drupal 8, this code doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation page for `hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x), this hook works in Drupal 8, but (as you can see in comments for the referenced article) you should place it in mymodule.views_execution.inc, not in mymodule.module.

Comment: Those comments aim to D7, they are wrong.

Comment: The only implementation of that hook done from Drupal core is placed in a *.views_execution.inc* file, similarly to the Drupal core implementations of [`hook_views_query_substitutions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_substitutions/8.2.x). It doesn't seem the choice of that file is random.

Answer (score 1):

Use it in .module file and change any query as you like

```
/**
     * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
     */
    function module-name_views_query_alter(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, $query) {

      if ($view->id() == 'example' && $view->current_display == 'example') {
        if (!empty($view->exposed_raw_input['company_name'])) {
          foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
            foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
              if ($condition['field'] == 'node_field_data.type') {
                $condition = array(
                  'field' => 'node_field_data.type',
                  'value' => 'abc',
                  'operator' => '=',
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: May you describe what exactly the OP needs to do to change his code?

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain more? For example, what is the company name? How does it sort the node_field_data_created? How to implement the filter?

Comment: Here 'company_name' is one of my field and i am changing the condition of othe field 'node_field_data' with some static value and operator is "="

Comment: I tried your code today. I didnt work it out. My purpose is reading menu and fetch the word from menu, then filter the content from this category. For example, 'music' is one of my menu word, then the filter will be 'music'. It will looking the nodes from 'music' category. Anyway, thank you a lot!